# SpeechSynthesisUtterance Chrome Issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am experiencing a problem (or a bug) with using the native SpeechSynthesisUtterance. I build a basic function "speak", that would take the given string "text" and pronounce it.

```
//Function for speaking text
function speak(text){
  if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
    var sentence = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    for(var i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
          if(voices[i]['name'] == "Alex"){
            sentence.voice = voices[i];
          }
      }
    sentence.pitch = 0.5;
    sentence.rate = 1;
    sentence.text = text;
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(sentence);
  } else {
    console.log("Oops! Your browser does not support HTML SpeechSynthesis.")
  }
}
```

This function works perfectly in Safari, selecting the voice "Alex" and then pronouncing the given text in that voice. In Chrome on the other hand, I've been experiencing an issue. For some reason the "Alex" is only select when called upon the function the second time in Chrome. The first time the function is called upon is speaks the text with the default female voice, but after that the voice is set to "Alex" and it works perfectly. I have limited this bug to being a Chrome issue, however, I'd still like it to be fixed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getVoices is asynchronus (mentioned in the Spec Errata) and you need to listen to the [voiceschanged event](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334847), the reasoning is a little frustrating but makes sense, the Voice system is lazily loaded and the first call to getVoices would block the main thread so the first call on android returns 0 results and then fires an `onvoiceschanged` when the voices become available.

```
// Chrome loads voices asynchronously.
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function(e) {
  loadVoices();
};
```

The [linked demo](http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/wGzuJ) incorrectly sets the `voice` attribute on the utterance.  This doesn't exist, instead you need to change the lang and optionally the voiceURI to change the default used voice as can be seen below and in the [new demo](https://output.jsbin.com/vayiti/latest).

```
if (voiceSelect.value) {
  var selectedVoice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) { return voice.voiceURI == voiceSelect.value; })[0];

  msg.voiceURI = selectedVoice.voiceURI;
  msg.lang = selectedVoice.lang;

}
```